# How to compile HLSL shaders with Vulkan?

Tags: c++, hlsl, vulkan, spir-v

I'm current learning Vulkan API, it's time to create pipeline, I chose HLSL because in the future I want to reuse shaders in DirectX and when I get an RTX GPU I intend to bring ray tracing, I'm new in HLSL, I wrote a simple vertex shader:

```
float4 main(float2 pos : POSITIONT) : SV_POSITION
{
    return float4(pos, 0, 1);
}
```

Following [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules) i try to compile: `glslc.exe VertexShader.hlsl -o vertex.spv`

And i get this error: `glslc: error: 'VertexShader.hlsl': .hlsl file encountered but no -fshader-stage specified ahead`

So, how to compile HLSL in Vulkan?

Comment: https://github.com/google/shaderc/tree/master/glslc#option-fshader-stage

Comment: @tkausl thanks, worked

Comment: @tkausl make a proper Answer

Comment: Making a proper answer allows the OP to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to use the DXC compiler (https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) which has a SPIR-V backend available. This would be the same compiler you end up using with DirectX as well.

Answer (score 2):

Solveld adding -fshader-stage=vertex